# how could i map virtual space in kernel to user space?

Tags: kernel, shared-memory

i want to shared a memeory space between user and kernel.
the first thing i want to do is allocating memory space in kernel, use `kmalloc` or `vmalloc` , and mapping the sapce to user for the second.
so i need to customize my `mmap` function, and the key to acheiving this is the function `remap_pfn_range`, which needs **pfn** of the space.

but the **pfn** is associated with physical page address,i need to transform the virtual address in kernel to physical address first.
i need a large space whose size is larger than a `PAGE_SIZE`, in this case `kmalloc` may not be appropriate because it allocate contiguous physical memory, and the memory may not be enough.
so i consider to use `vmalloc` instead.
but the question comes: the `vmalloc` allocate non-contiguous physical memory,so i need to get every pages allocated and do mapping for all of them . how can i do that?
and is there any way to map kernel memory to user space directly,which means i needn't to transoform the kernel address to physical address first ,and than map the physical pages to user secondly?
i do some works just like:

```
{
    int ret;
    unsigned long size = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    pr_info("vma->vm_start: %p\n", vma->vm_start);
    pr_info("vma->vm_end: %p\n", vma->vm_end);
    pr_info("memory: %p\n", memory);
    unsigned long pfn = vmalloc_to_pfn(k_qp);
    pr_info("pfn: %ld\n", pfn);
    if (size > PAGE_SIZE)
    {
        pr_err("size too large\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    ret = remap_pfn_range(vma,
                          vma->vm_start,
                          pfn,
                          size,
                          vma->vm_page_prot);

    pr_info("remap_pfn_range ret: %d\n", ret);
    return ret;
}
```

the `memory` is pointing to the memory using `vmalloc` before(size is smaller than PAGE_SIZE). when i try to get the pfn ,it returns a strenge value. and the size i calculate in kernel seems to be different from what userspace specifies due to the vma i get . here's the debug info:

```
[28288.407882] memory: 00000000a60b865d
[28288.409341] vma->vm_start: 140257261522944
[28288.409351] vma->vm_end: 140257261527040
[28288.409362] pfn: 406657
[28288.414843] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffe9ff0b79a488
[28288.414856] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[28288.414865] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[28288.414873] PGD 0 P4D 0 
[28288.414904] Oops: 0000 [#5] SMP NOPTI
```

so why the erro comes? and how can i fix it ?

Comment: This design is almost always a Bad Idea.  ioctls are quick, and a more reliable way of communicating.  What do you expect to do with this memory region?  Where did `vma` come from?

Comment: I know that ioctl can customize some kernel behaviors and expose interfaces to users, and is it easier to  achive my goal? i just want to share a memory space between user and kernel for data exchanging,which and avoid the overhead of frequently switching between user and kernel mode. and i think `vma` has been initialized according to parameters specified by user when user call `mmap` .is this wrong?@TimRoberts

Comment: But to successfully do "data exchanging", you will need some kind of interlock or notification scheme, and that means you will be doing user/kernel transitions already.  You might as well use the safer ioctls and combine the notification with the data transfers.

Comment: Usually, you would get the pfn from `vma->vm_pgoff`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes,you're right.But if it is in data exchange, this should reduce the data copy once, and if I use this space for request storage, then the user request does not even need to go through the system call. Of course, this needs to consider security and concurrency issues.And my `pfn` seems correct@TimRoberts

Comment: If you don't go through the system call, how will the kernel side know there is work to be done?  Remember that CPUs today can copy tens of gigabytes per second.